# Meteor cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm having an issue where in production only (not development) I get hundreds of `cannot read property 'click' of undefined` with 3-30 on each click, and a few `cannot read property 'submit' of undefined`.  This very well may not be an issue with Meteor but with my code, so I'm just looking for any ideas why this may be happening or how I can debug it.  All my events are either in `Template.events` or `Template.rendered`.  It happens on every page and no matter where I click.

Comment: So, you run the same code in two environments and it produces different results?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a site where this is happening? Have you tried looking at the stack trace and setting a debug point at the place the error is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that can cause this.

The first is that in production mode latency is a lot higher. So if you've automatically assumed that when a template is rendered the data is ready you could get all sorts of `undefined` as the object's are `null` for a very short time when meteor initally loads.

You could check your code to see if you've used any `findOne` or `find`. You need to ensure that the result of your query is properly handled in the case that there aren't any results, for that initial load. i.e

```
var data = myCollection.findOne(...);

if(data) {
....
}
```

or

```
var data = myCollection.find(...);

if(data.count()>0) {
....
}
```

The other thing that might cause it are atmosphere packages that you're using that might not be mapped correctly.

To check this have a look at your network tab in the chrome inspector:

[image]

Look through for files whos extensions don't match their content (js & css files).

If a file is a `.js` file it might have HTML content (Meteor doesn't serve up 404 errors, instead giving them html whichever path is called, so no explicit errors are given).

If this is the case figure out which file it is and map it correctly. (You might be calling click to a plugin that didn't load correctly). In production mode files are minified and the package paths change so this might also be it.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what happened but when I checked again this morning I'm not getting the errors anymore.  Although, you helped me solve another issue without even knowing I had it, so thanks lol.  I was getting a ton of `Exception from Deps afterFlush function: undefined` but as I check for latency I'm definitely getting a lot less of them and hopefully will be down to 0 soon.